# WSO2 ESB is making duplicate requests

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have a proxy service which works well, it is requested from task on WSO2 ESB, 
but sometimes it makes duplicate requests when sending XML body into call mediator.
Why sometimes is it duplicated?
Maybe I should get some advice about this structure?
Can someone help me with this proxy service?

```
<proxy name="MyServiceStartOperProxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="https http" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence onError="CustomFaultHandlerForWs_Sequence">
            <property expression="fn:normalize-space($body//PaymentDate)" name="PrPaymentDate" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <filter xpath="get-property('PrPaymentDate') = ''">
                <then>
                    <property expression="get-property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'yyyy-MM-dd')" name="PrPaymentDate" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                </then>
                <else>
                    <property expression="get-property('PrPaymentDate')" name="PrPaymentDate" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                </else>
            </filter>
            <property expression="get-property('MyServiceSettingsXml_Local-entries')" name="LocalEntriesXML" scope="default" type="OM"/>
            <property expression="fn:concat($ctx:LocalEntriesXML//*[local-name()='HostPortWS'], '/services/MyServiceSendToMethod1_Proxy')" name="uri.var.PrWSAddress" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <dat:MyServiceGetCardPaymentDataService_Operation xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                        <dat:PaymentDate>$1</dat:PaymentDate>
                    </dat:MyServiceGetCardPaymentDataService_Operation>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('PrPaymentDate')"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <header name="Action" scope="default" value="MyServiceGetCardPaymentDataService_Operation"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="ProxyName" value="MyServiceStartOperProxy.inSequence BeforeCall MyServiceSendToMethod1_Proxy"/>
            </log>
            <property description="Convert application/xml format to text/xml format, because got response application/xml format" name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/xml"/>
            <property description="Convert application/xml format to text/xml format, because got response application/xml format" name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/xml"/>
            <!------------------------------------------------------------->
            <!--Here happen problem, endpoint is called two times-->
            <!------------------------------------------------------------->
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="post" uri-template="{uri.var.PrWSAddress}"/>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="ProxyName" value="MyServiceStartOperProxy.inSequence AfterCall MyServiceSendToMethod1_Proxy"/>
            </log>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
        ..................
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <publishWSDL key="gov:_system/config/resources/MyServiceStartOperProxyCustom.wsdl" preservePolicy="true"/>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

The given synapse configuration does not seem to contain any issues. As per the given description task is invoking the proxy service and you are experiencing there are duplicate requests going out from the proxy service. Following are some of the steps to narrow down the issue,

- Since you have added a custom log **ProxyName**. Do you observe that duplicated custom log messages are printed in the carbon log? If so it means that the task is invoking the proxy service multiple times and you will have to troubleshoot the task that is invoking the proxy
- How did you observe there are duplicated requests going out of the ESB server. Did you enable wire logs to monitor this?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply!  1) Yes, I observed that duplicated custom log messages are printed in the carbon log. 
2) No, I didn't.  I didn't know about  wire logs, but I felt that something like this have to be, so thank to you for opened this for me.

Comment: Problem was that out admin corrected time in two linux servers few days ago and in proxy services became requested service WSAddress from  only from one server, because they both had the same address other proxy service of  one ESB.
I think it can be better added Throttle M to restrict access by IPs
and add property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR')  because if i noted some IP in a log i would undestood what is problem quikly